# Stream a camera, and get the video feed on Java

Tags: java, webcam, streaming

For my project, I have two USB cameras. I would like to plug them to the Raspberry Pi to stream over the internet. Also, I am developing a software in Java, and these videos streams (2) have to be displayed on the Java Application.

I saw that numerous solution can stream a webcam from RPI, but I would like to know how to get the feed in order to display it on Java.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to raspberrypi.se! To be able to help you, some additional information would be great! What did you try so far, and how did the result differ from what you expected?